# Regex is only showing one result how can I get it to show the rest of the results in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I been looking for a while on google and on here and I can't find a post that is very helpful so I have this script that gets each class name id value and put it in a variable call strtext so later I use regex

to output the value of the var output but I'm noticing it is only showing the var output result as one match which is showing just

**a**

so how can I get the regex section to show the rest of the matches.
I'm referring to this

```
document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML= output;
```

Here is my code

```js
var names= document.querySelectorAll('.name');

var text = new Array();
var strtext = '';
 
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
var arlength = text.length;
text[arlength] = '['+names[i].getAttribute('id')+']';
}
strtext = text.join(' and ');
document.querySelector('#output-1').innerHTML= strtext;

//Show all the regex matches
var string= strtext;
var pattern= /\[(.*?)\]/ig;
var match = pattern.exec(string);
var output= match[1];
document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML= output;
```

```html
<p id='a' class='name'>Adam</p>
<p id='b' class='name'>Bob</p>
<p id='c' class='name'>Cane</p>
<p id='d' class='name'>Dan</p>
<p id='e' class='name'>Ed</p>
<p id='f' class='name'>Fred</p>
<p id='g' class='name'>Gene</p>

<p id='output-1'></p>
<p id='output-2'></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call '`pattern.exec`' multiple times, as long as it succeeds, like this:

```
var output = "";
var match = pattern.exec(string);
while (match !== null && match.length)
{
    output += match[1];
    match = pattern.exec(string);
}
document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML = output;
```

This should get you all results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but sadly there is an error with your suggestion this is what is says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var it is referencing to  this while (var match = pattern.exec(string) !== null) This is what I put //Show all the regex matches
var string= strtext;
var pattern= /\[(.*?)\]/ig;
var output = "";
while (var match = pattern.exec(string) !== null)
{
    output += match[1];
}
document.querySelector('#output-2').innerHTML = output;

Comment: I have made a small edit, hope it Works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can depend on the names being name-like (and not having, for example, square brackets in them), then you can get all results at once with a regular expression match, for non-bracket characters, with lookahead for a `]`.

You can also use dot notation to access the `id` of an element, which is a lot easier than using `getAttribute('id')`.

Also, unless you're deliberately inserting HTML markup, it's quicker, safer, and more predictable to assign to `textContent` to assign text content, rather than `innerHTML`:

```js
var names = document.querySelectorAll('.name');

var text = new Array();
var strtext = '';

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var arlength = text.length;
  text[arlength] = '[' + names[i].id + ']';
}
strtext = text.join(' and ');
document.querySelector('#output-1').textContent = strtext;
document.querySelector('#output-2').textContent =
  strtext.match(/[^[\]]+(?=\])/g).join('');
```

```html
<p id='a' class='name'>Adam</p>
<p id='b' class='name'>Bob</p>
<p id='c' class='name'>Cane</p>
<p id='d' class='name'>Dan</p>
<p id='e' class='name'>Ed</p>
<p id='f' class='name'>Fred</p>
<p id='g' class='name'>Gene</p>

<p id='output-1'></p>
<p id='output-2'></p>
```

The regular expression in the code above

```
[^[\]]+(?=\])
```

means:

`[^[\]]` - A character matching anything but a `[` or a `]`

`+` - Repeat the preceeding character set as much as possible

`(?=\])` - Lookahead for a literal `]` after the last matched character